# Question regarding the properties of multiplication vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have two N-dimensional column vectors, x and y. I need to prove that

$$(y^T x) x = (x x^T)y$$

I have done the following. Since $y^T x$ is scalar, we know that $y^T x = x^T y$ so we have

$$(y^T x) x = x (y^T x) = x (x^T y)$$

But I dont know for sure how to go from here to what I need to prove.

My idea is that since x and y are basically 1 dimensional matrices, can we say that the associativity property holds and therefore

$$x (x^T y) = x x^T y = (x x^T) y$$

Thanks in advance for every insight you can give me.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your idea. Although, note that this is very easy to prove the long way by just multiplying everything out.

Comment: I thought about that but i wasnt sure if multiplying everything and going all the way to the simplest form is a valid proof :P

Comment: Honestly, I would have done it the long way. Your way is much better and far more informative for later math.

Comment: To be a little more clear, technically speaking, $y^Tx$ is a 1x1 matrix, so its transpose equals itself. Then $y^Tx=(y^Tx)^T=x^Ty$.

Comment: Yeah ive incorporated that thought. Thanks a lot for the insight.

Comment: What I mean is that this is what I did in the second row of equations, where I say that $x(y^T x) = x(x^T y)$ since $x(y^T x) = x(y^T x)^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is nothing but the associativity of the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you. I wasnt sure but yeah, 1 dimensional vectors are still matrices hehe